# Problems with fluid grid logic when viewing with Safari (desktop and laptop) - repost with edits

Tags: html, css

I am using fluid grid on website.  The logic is working great on larger screens desktop, laptop, phone, tablet, and ipad when viewing with IE, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  For some reason on laptop and desktop, the divs are stacking on top of each other as if it was viewing on a phone.  Although I am only showing one page and the css along with it, the problem is recurring across all pages.  I changed names of classes in css based on what I was needing it for.  I believe just viewing the site and looking at the css will paint a better picture of what the problem is.  Just about every page is exhibiting that problem. the example that I included below is for the footer section of each page. http://jandswebsitedesigns.com/test/index.html  Thanks!

```
 <style>
 .container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
   }

   .c1, .c2  {
     width: 100%;
   }

  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    .c1, .c2 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    }


  @media (min-width: 800px) {
   .c1, .c2, {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .container {
      width: 800px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }

 .container {
 margin: 0;  
  padding: 0;  
  width: 100%; }

  .container div {
  box-sizing: border-box;  }

 </style>

  <div id="footer">  
   <div id="footer-content">
   <div class="container" style="margin:  0; 
      padding:  35px 0 35px 0;" role="main">

         <div class="c1" style="padding-bottom:  25px;">
             <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
                <div id="site-map">
                    <p class="footer-hdr">Navigation</p>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a><br />
                    <a href="im-new-here.html">I'm New Here</a><br />
                    <a href="sermons.html">Sermon Archive</a><br />
                    <a href="ministries.html">Ministries</a><br />
                    <a href="next-steps.html">Next Steps</a><br />
                    <a href="learn-more.html">Learn More</a><br />
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br />
                    <a href="give.html">Give</a><br />
                 </div>
               </div>
             <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
                <div id="site-map">
                  <p class="footer-hdr">About</p>
                  <a href="learn-more.html">Core Values</a><br />
                  <a href="beliefs.html">Beliefs</a><br />
                  <a href="the-team.html">The Team</a><br />
                  <a href="missions.html">Missions</a><br />
               </div>
             </div>
        </div><!--close c1-->
       <div class="c2">
           <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
             <div id="site-map">
             <p class="footer-hdr">Connect</p>
                  <a href="kids.html">Kids</a><br />
                  <a href="students.html">Students</a><br />
                  <a href="adults.html">Adults</a><br />
                  <a href="marrieds.html">Marrieds</a><br />
                  <a href="mens.html">Men's</a><br />
                  <a href="womens.html">Women's</a><br />
                  <a href="young-adults.html">Young Adults</a><br />
                </div>
            </div>

      <div style="float:  left;  width:  50%;">
         <div id="site-map" style="color:  #979797; line-height:  150%;">
            <p class="footer-hdr">Contact Info</p>
            <span style="color:  #ffffff;">Address</span>
             <br />5801 McArdle Rd.<br />Corpus Christi, TX
               <br />78412<br /><br />
        <span style="color:  #ffffff;">Church Office</span>
            <br />Phone:  (361) 992-9921<br />Fax:  (361) 992-1355
            <br /><br />
        <span style="color:  #ffffff;">Office Hours</span>
                 <br />Monday - Thursday<br />8:00am - 5:00pm 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><!--close c2-->
    </div><!-- close container-->


         </div><!--end footer content-->

        </div><!--end footer-->
```